# How to explode a string that has very specific set of characters in php?

Tags: php

If I have a text output like this:

```
a. Hello my name is xxx.
b. Hello is my name yyy?
c. Hello my name is rrr!
d. Hello my name is aaa
```

All the sentences may finish with different kinds of characters, so the critical issue to solve is separating the string based on the [letter]. string.
The text comes as 1 single string:

$string = "a. Hello my name is xxx.b. Hello is my name yyy?c. Hello my name is rrr!d. Hello my name is aaa";

I want to take the string and explode each sentence based on:

```
a.
b.
c.
d.
```

Then put each sentence into an array.

This is where I am at, for now, the delimiters are:
a. b. c. d.

```
<?php
$input = "a. Hello world aaa.
b. Hello world bbb,
c. Hello world ccc?
d. Hello world ddd!
e. Hello world eee;
f. Hello world fff?"

$regex = '^1\..*2\..*3\..*4\..*5\..*6\..*$';

echo preg_match($regex, $input);
```

Comment: Look at [preg_split](https://www.php.net/preg_split) and figure out a regular expression that matches your pattern.

Comment: So what are your delimiters?

Comment: I have added more to the question at the bottom(my example) to show you where I struggle and my regex

Comment: You want to explode also on `a.` and this sentence `a. Hello world aaa.` contains `a.` 
 twice?  Please make clearly known what you expect the exact output to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made one with [preg_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).

```
$str = "a. Hello my name is xxx.
b. Hello is my name yyy?
c. Hello my name is rrr!
d. Hello my name is aaa";
$res = preg_split("/\n[a-z].\s/", "\n" . $str);
array_shift($res);
print_r($res);
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello my name is xxx.
    [1] => Hello is my name yyy?
    [2] => Hello my name is rrr!
    [3] => Hello my name is aaa
)
```

See: [PHP fiddle](https://3v4l.org/miP1K)

The regular expression looks for four characters:

1. `\n` a line-feed
2. `[a-z]` character between a-z
3. `.` a point
4. `\s` any whitespace

Comment: Perfect thanks, straight to the point.